# Remote desktop connection between rpi4 and windows 11

Tags: ssh

I am facing this error for a while now. The picture below is the error i always encounter. Any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: You seem to be trying to connect to localhost (127.0.0.1) which is a local ip address on that same machine! What is the ip address of the Pi4 and the Win11 machine?